# call Lotus Notes client (to send an email) from another app

Tags: ipad, lotus-notes

I have an app which has the facility to email the contents of the page displayed.
It calls the default mail client of iPad. I want it to invoke the LOTUS NOTES client installed in the iPad when the action is triggered. 
How do I go about doing that ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this, I'm assuming by notes client you're referring to Lotus Notes Traveller. There's no associated uri defined to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use non-default mail client in iOS from inside other programs. It require using non-public API and it's prohibited by Apple.